# ItextSharp - RazorPdf put image on Pdf

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf

How can I put an image on the itextSharp generated pdf?

I have a simple method at the controller...

```
    public ActionResult Pdf()
    {

        var pdfResult = new PdfResult(null,"Pdf");
        pdfResult.ViewBag.Title = "Title";

        return pdfResult;
    }
```

And a simple view...

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<itext creationdate="@DateTime.Now.ToString()" producer="RazorPDF">

    Html Text for test.

    <img src="~/Images/sampleImage.png" />

</itext>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

try:

`<image url="@Context.Server.MapPath("~/Images/sampleImage.png")" />`

and check out the samples over at [github](https://github.com/RazorAnt/RazorPDFSample)

Comment: Marc How to add custom height and width to the image instead of re-sizing it??

Comment: @NikiteshKolpe I've never been able to find that out but I usually just throw it into a table and change the `widths` in `<table width="100%" cell-padding="0.5" widths ="5;2">`. the Image then seems to scale

Answer (score 0):

just change the source as shown below:

```
 <img src="@Context.Server.MapPath("~/Images/sampleImage.png")" width="100" height="100"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
<div style="margin:auto;width:60%;padding:10px;">
    <img src="@Server.MapPath("~/assets/img/image.png")" />
</div>
```