# Adding watermark to razorpdf mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, itext, razorpdf

I am using the following code to generate pdf in mvc using itext with razorpdf producer

```
@model myModel.Models.Examform
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<itext creationdate="@DateTime.Now.ToString()" producer="RazorPDF">
    Hello
</text>
```

This code works fine. I want to add a watermark to the generated pdf. I know how to add the image. I need a watermark which shows in the background.

Comment: I have this solved using iTextSharp, is that the same thing as itext?

Answer (score 1):

this is pretty much the exact same question

[ItextSharp - RazorPdf put image on Pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18049461/itextsharp-razorpdf-put-image-on-pdf)

so using the answer there should work for you:

```
<image url="@Context.Server.MapPath("~/Images/sampleImage.png")" />
```

Edit: To overlay text on the image, you need to modify your CSS and HTML.

[How to position text over an image in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708945/how-to-position-text-over-an-image-in-css)

[Add "Watermark" effect with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625706/add-watermark-effect-with-css)

http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/textoverimage/

You *might* need to put the CSS inline.

Comment: I know how to add an image. I want to know how to add a watermark or an image which will show in the background.

Comment: @MaryPhelps - I've added more to my answer.

Comment: None of the options mentioned by you are working. They will all work in a normal html page. They are not working in case of razorpdf.

Comment: well, the way we did it was to use the rotativa library https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rotativa/

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have done. The code goes in the controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public FileStreamResult Certificate(MyModel model)
{
    Stream fileStream = GeneratePDF(model);
    HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=Certificate.pdf");

    var fileStreamResult = new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "application/pdf");
    return fileStreamResult;
}

public Stream GeneratePDF(HomeViewModel model)
{ 
    var rect = new Rectangle(288f, 144f);
    var doc = new Document(rect, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    BaseFont bfArialNarrow = BaseFont.CreateFont(Server.MapPath("../Content/fonts/ARIALN.ttf"), BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

    //Full Background Image (Includes watermark)
    Image fullBackground = null;
    fullBackground = Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("../Content/images/Certificate/Cert1.jpg"));

    doc.SetPageSize(PageSize.LETTER.Rotate());

    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, memoryStream);
    doc.Open();

    //Full Background Image
    fullBackground.Alignment = Image.UNDERLYING | Image.ALIGN_CENTER | Image.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
    doc.Add(fullBackground);

    Font myFont = new Font(bfArialNarrow, 57);
    var myParagraph = new Paragraph("Some text here.", myFont);
    doc.Add(myParagraph);

    pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;
    doc.Close();

    memoryStream.Position = 0;

    return memoryStream;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible via markup.

If you have a look at PdfView.cs in RazorPDF source code, it uses XmlParser or HtmlParser in iTextsharpt to render pdf.

https://github.com/RazorAnt/RazorPDF/blob/master/RazorPDF/PdfView.cs

The support of markups in these two classes are limited. You can only do what they have implemented.

The alternative way is to use iTextsharp to create pdf via code.